# Do I need to re-instantiate EditContext if Value changes?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a parameter:

```
[Parameter]
public RateItemModel Value { get; set; } = default!;
```

My razor page has:

```
<EditForm EditContext="EditContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmitAsync" OnInvalidSubmit="HandleInvalidSubmitAsync" Context="editFormContext">
```

And during initialization I do the following:

```
EditContext = new EditContext(Value);
```

Do I need to override `OnParametersSetAsync()` and whenever `Value` is changed, re-instantiate `EditContext`?

**Update:**

Here's the use case. I have a list of signup cards. Each signup card let's you click to attend or not attend. When the user clicks, the card remains up, but the changed commitment has to be written to the DB and the card needs to display the changed commitment value.

The easy solution is to write the new value to SignupCard.Commitment but that's a no-no. So...

1. The user's click changes the Model.Commitment value and calls `OnClick`.
2. The OnClick creates a `Signup` object with the `Commitment` property set to the new value.
3. The `EventCard` component calls `ValueChanged` passing this `Signup` object to the parent list page.
4. The list page has an array that it assigned to `ListPage.Data` that is assigned to the `DxListBox.Values` property of the DxListBox.
5. It performs a shallow copy of this list to a temp list var.
6. The changed signup is assigned to `list[index]` in that temp list, overwriting the old value.
7. The data is also updated in the DB.
8. This list is assigned to 'ListPage.Data`
9. The `DxListBox.Values` property is thereby changed. So it now updates the `SignupCard.Value` for all the cards in the list.
10. The `SignupCard` that started all this now gets a new `Value`.
11. This is now applied to the "`ignupCard.Model` (which should change nothing).
12. And I believe I also need to re-create `EditContext` using this new `Value`.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that `RateItemModel ` and therefore each card has multiple fields that the user can edit? And you need to validate something in there such as a text field?  I am a bit confused as your edit context is on a `RateItemModel` instance but your ValueChanged returns a `SignUp` object.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I have the two different objects because the page needs something to edit and I'm supposed to tread the `Value` object (which is a `Signup` object) as read only. So the object directly edited on the page is the `RateItemModel` object. And yes, it has multiple fields (2 ints and a string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demo MRE I've built from your description.  I've made some guesses to fill in the gaps, and am using standard controls instead of the expensive DX stuff.

It uses a dictionary to track the data objects.

It probably provides a different insight into how to implement what you are trying to do.  There's an issue if you edit a value and then go elsewhere, but I not going to show how to solve that until I'm sure my MRE is a close approximation to your use case.

My Data objects:

```cs
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; init; }  //Normally I would use a Guid, but you're probably using an int
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int Likes { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastEdit { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;  //dirty but quick way of tracking equality
}
```

```cs
// Demo Data provider
public static class CountryProvider
{
    private static List<Country> _countries = new()
        {
            new() {Id = 1, Name = "France", Likes= 1 },
            new() {Id = 2, Name = "UK", Likes= 0 },
            new() {Id = 3, Name = "Spain", Likes= 4 },
            new() {Id = 4, Name = "Portugal", Likes= 5 },
        };

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<Country>> GetCountries()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return _countries.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public static async Task SaveAsync(Country country)
    {
        // Do the save
        await Task.Delay(50);
    }
}
```

```cs
public record LikesData(int Id);
```

The "Card"

```cs
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">@Value.Name</div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="alert alert-primary p-2 m-2"> Likes: @_model.Likes</div>
        <EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="Submit">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_model.Name" />
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update</button>
            </div>
        </EditForm>
        <div class="m-2 text-end">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="UpdateLikes">Like</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public Country Value { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Country> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<LikesData> LikesChanged { get; set; }

    private EditContext? _editContext;
    private Country _model = new();

    // This is here so we have all our data sorted before any first render
    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.Value);

        // Timestamp used to track edit state.  You can use what mechanism you like
        // I use value objects for all my data simplifying equality checking
        // Country would be public record Country{};
        // and here i would create a CountryEditContext object for editing
        if (this.Value.LastEdit != _model.LastEdit)
        {
            _model = new()
                {
                    Id = this.Value.Id,
                    Name = this.Value.Name,
                    Likes = this.Value.Likes,
                    LastEdit = this.Value.LastEdit,
                };
            _editContext = new(_model);
        }

        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    //Your return object may be more complex so I've used a value object rather than just an int
    private async Task UpdateLikes()
    {
        await this.LikesChanged.InvokeAsync(new(this.Value.Id));
    }

    // Form submit on validation.
    private async Task Submit()
    {
        _model.LastEdit = DateTime.Now;
        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_model);
    }
}
```

And the Page:

```cs
<div class="row">
    @foreach(var country in _countries )
    {
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <CountryCard @key="country.Value.Id"
            Value="country.Value" 
            ValueChanged="this.UpdateCountry" 
            LikesChanged="this.UpdateLikes" />
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {

    // use a dictionary so we can separate out the index from the object and only replace the object on an update
    private Dictionary<int, Country> _countries = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var countries = await CountryProvider.GetCountries();
        // normally need to check here if you have a list here and do something if you don't
        foreach(var country in countries)
            _countries.Add(country.Id, country);
    }

    private async  Task UpdateCountry(Country country)
    {
        _countries[country.Id] = country;
        await CountryProvider.SaveAsync(country);
    }

    private void UpdateLikes(LikesData value)
    {
        _countries[value.Id].Likes++;
        _countries[value.Id].LastEdit = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The one difference I have from your is my `_model` class is lightweight (i.e. no `_model.Name` property) while my `Value` class is the full DB model object that has additional properties (i.e. `Value.Name`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do.  Because you cqn't *reset* the context.  If you set the context to a new object, the whole `EditForm` [including edit controls] will rebuild.

However, on the assumption that `RateItemModel` is a class i.e. reference object, your question raises several issues.

1. How do you detect if `Value` has changed?  Reference changes are OK, but what if you mutate the object outside the Edit context.  Have you overridden the equal comparators for your data class, and then checked equality in `OnParametersSet`?
2. Why would `Value` change, and the parent component force a render cascade event?  If the parent renderers then your edit component will because `Value` is a object, so it renders it because it can't detect whether or not `Value` has changed.

On the assumption that you can detect a change, you need to consider two cases:

1. The current form is clean, how do you tell the user that the data has changed and the form has reloaded?
2. The current form is dirty.  How do you resolve the differences?

Comment: I added an update above with all the steps. A reference equality comparison should work for this as I am creating a new object on a change. And the user will see the change when they click while all of the steps after that are just getting all the data everywhere to now match the change the user just made.